# How to use SUM() in an MySql expression

Tags: mysql, sql

Using `MySql WorkBench`, in `table1` I want to put in every cell of the column `item_quantiy_total` de sum of the column `item_quantity`. I tried the expression `SUM(item_quantity)`, but that was rejected. What would be the correct expression?

[image]

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have such a table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM TestTable;
+---------------+
| item_quantity |
+---------------+
|            12 |
|            25 |
|            16 |
|            90 |
|           120 |
+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

USE window functions to achieve it:

```
mysql> SELECT item_quantity, SUM(item_quantity) OVER() AS item_quantity_total FROM TestTable;
+---------------+--------------------+
| item_quantity | item_quantiy_total |
+---------------+--------------------+
|            12 |                263 |
|            25 |                263 |
|            16 |                263 |
|            90 |                263 |
|           120 |                263 |
+---------------+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for an expression that could be inserted in the table itself, without running any query, very much like Excel calculates cells. The script syntax to use would be `CHANGE COLUMN item_quantity_total item_quantity_total INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (xxx) VIRTUAL`. I would like to know what to replace the `xxx` with ;

Comment: Hi @Steven, I understand your point. I tried to do it using first window functions, then common table expressions (cte's), and lastly using user defined variables; but syntax doesn't support neither of these structures. So I give up. Stay safe!

Comment: Will every row in the table always have the same value for this column?

Comment: @ChrisStrickland yes, exactly! Just use OVER() clause with no parameter(I mean, PARTITION BY)

Comment: @Steven: you might be able to accomplish this with a trigger using an UPDATE statement without a where parameter so that it updates the entire table.  https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/